# Some windows are invisible in the Unity switcher

Tags: unity, application-switcher

[image]

When I try to switch from one window to another with Unity toolbar, some windows are invisible as shown in the screenshot. You can better understand it from the snapshot of the desktop.

Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/yKQBY.jpg this is the print screen

Comment: Please use words as well to describe your problem.

Comment: The problem is when using command alt + tab and the rest of the tabs do not appear.

Answer (score 0):

The invisible windows are minimised.

As far as I can tell, this is intentional because a minimised window can't have it's contents seen.